# Passing user data from one activity to the next, data is from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two activities. One activity lets the user login using email/password verification of Firebase. Once the user is logged in, I am passing the FIREBASE_URL to the next activity. How would I go about extracting the details of the signed-in user from the new Firebase(url)?

Comment: need more info, like how is your database structured?, do you use the user UID to get the user specific data?

Comment: I am passing the firebase URL to the seconAcitivity and the UID of the signed in user.

Comment: if you're storing your user specific data as a list of user UIDs, then it's pretty simple, get the FirebaseDatabaseReference and then access the user's data using the `child` method passing the user UID.

Comment: CAn you exaplin further please?

Comment: for instance, if you're storing your user data like this :
`-> root (list) [ UID1, UID2, UID3..etc ]
`
then it's pretty simple, just call FirebaseDatabase.getRef(userUID);
this way you have the user node, if you want to query on it, attach a ValueEventListener to it...and so on.
to be honest I've never used/saw anyone using firebase URLs before.

Comment: This is my second day using firebase, so am learning on the fly. How do people usually pass user data then. Because the regular firebase email/password authentication does not pass that infor apart from the UID

Comment: Sorry for being late.
if you want to set/update/delete/query user data you should use firebase real-time database
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Did that, worked very well thanks.